# Shell script to check for string and special characters

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a sample shell script, I have to perform some operation if the string is not equal to "sample" and string doesn't contain special characters. I tried below code, but I'm getting syntax errors. Is this proper way of doing it? If not, what's the correct way of doing it?

```
#!/bin/bash
  str='sudo'
  if [ "$str" != "sample" ] && [[ "$str" != *['!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]* ]]
  then
      echo "Proceed"
  else
       echo "Stop"
  fi
```

I'm getting syntax errors like this :

```
bash-3.2$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 3: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
./test.sh: line 3: syntax error near `&*()'
./test.sh: line 3: `if [ "$str" != "sample" ] || [[ "$str" != *['!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]* ]]'
```

Comment: If you are getting syntax errors, you aren't running the script with `bash`. It's perfectly valid `bash` code.

Comment: @chepner Thank you . Please see the updated content

Comment: Ah, this looks like it might be a parser bug in 3.2. It's definitely fixed in 4.3; I'm not sure how much earlier it might have been fixed, or if it is explicitly mentioned in the release notes. Escaping the parentheses (`\(\)`) appears to work in 3.2 and 4.x.

Answer (score 2):

This might be an alternative

```
#!/bin/bash
 str='sudo'
 if ! [ "$str" = "sample" ] && ! [[ "$str" =~ [^[:alnum:]]+ ]]
 then
   echo "Proceed"
 else
   echo "Stop"
 fi
```

**Note**

1. Check bash [[ character classes ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html).
2. The `^` before the a character class negates it, in essence we are looking for anything other that alphanumeric
3. Similarly `!` before a test expression negates it.
4. `+` checks for at least one occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

everythink ok on bash shell.

```
user@host:/tmp$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
  str='sudo'
  if [ "$str" != "sample" ] && [[ "$str" != *['!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]* ]]
  then
      echo "Proceed"
  else
       echo "Stop"
  fi

user@host:/tmp$ ./test.sh 

Proceed
```

if you run like as below, this could be wrong result.

```
user@host:/tmp$  ksh test.sh
Stop
```